# How to make local mirror of a website with a confirmation popup?

Tags: wget, chrome

I need to get a local copy of a website which requires confirming one's age before displaying content. No complex forms, just a checkbox and a button, "yes, I'm adult". I tried to use `wget` but with no success, it only downloads this initial screen and nothing more. Httrack failed, too.

I believe the confirmation info is stored in a cookie file, and I think I found out which one it is. So I copied it using the [cookie.txt export](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookietxt-export/lopabhfecdfhgogdbojmaicoicjekelh) chromium extension, then saved it to .txt and tried `wget` once again with `--load-cookies` option, but it still doesn't work.

How do I download website such as this one? Am I misusing `wget` or maybe there's a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**

OK, DownThemAll seems to do the work. Finally, I succeeded with `wget` as well, using

```
wget -mpkrl 0 http://example.com
```

maybe `-rl 0` was what I was missing previously.

After investigating the page source I found that there's no reloading/redirecting involved, subpages are downloaded correctly and the confirmation screen is just an `iframe` on top of the page, so I can get rid of it with some simple script.

*(In this particular case messing with cookies eventually was not necessary, so I'm not posting this as an answer.)*

Comment: For anything all that advanced I would look into using `curl` instead of `wget`, curl can do some pretty complex stuff with forms and cookies. I would start with [this curl tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) and work your way up from that.

Comment: @JoelDavis, `wget` was enough this time, but thanks for the tutorial anyway, it seems very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the site is set-up, not all of them use cookies for this - some may use things like php-sessions, and I don't know if wget can handle it directly.  If you manage find the session-id (that part often gets hidden in the address-line by the browser or only used once as you log-in), you may be able to use that (the URL+session-id) as the start-url for wget.

Back to cookies... I have however needed to do similar things myself, so a few tips...

Some sites use cookies that are temporarily, ie. only last this session.  These are usually *not* stored in the cookie.txt/cookies-database, so not all cookie-exporters will export them - if it exports from file/database, then no... if it exports from the browser-"memory" (on a site-base), then yes.  `Personally, I've found the "cookie.txt export" extension for the Chrome-browser the best, as it saves *all* cookies (including temps) from just the active tab.` (well, actually it shows the cookies as text, you must mark&copy it and save it to file yourself)   For a log-in; checking "Remember Me", will often turn a temporary cookie not stored in the cookie-file/database into a permanent one, so it can be easily exported (probably won't help for age-confirmation though).

After you've stored the cookies.txt file, it may be a good idea to edit it a bit - increase the expiration-time and perhaps editing the temp-cookies into permanent ones (think it's just a "switch").  You may also delete any non-related cookies (ie. ads and such).

Keeping the browser-window open while wget works - and perhaps refreshing the page or browsing a bit now and then - will make sure your session won't be expired before wget-finishes.

There are also extensions to browsers...  I like "Down-them-all" for Firefox; which let you download content (though more interactively than wget).  You get a list of links of the current page, and just check the links and/or images you want to save - and optionally, how many levels in depth you want to follow links.  If you first log-in and/or check your age before starting it, then Down-them-all will be logged-in and checked-in together with your browser, and should be able to download all you could download manually.  Play around with the renaming-patterns and numbering, as I think it'll store all pages flatly and there otherwise may be naming-conflict (it'll ask before overwriting though).

Good luck!